# VB.net Listbox Autoscroll

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox, autoscroll

Well I am trying to autoscroll my ListBox or display everything the opposite way just like a shoutbox.

Please post the code here on how to do it. I have tried many ways but they either gave me errors or didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just usethe `ListBox.TopIndex` property.

Here's the help for it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.topindex.aspx

Or otherwise you could just insert the new items on the top rather than the bottom.

As a general tip though, if you're having problems getting the `ListBox` to do what you need, it might be worth using a `ListView` in details mode instead.

Comment: How can I insert new items at the top?

Comment: Off the top of my head and assuming the `ListBox` is called list I think it would be something like `list.Items.Insert(0, YourStringOrObject)`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use on vb.net 2008 pro and it works for me.
Just make sure you don't have it set to multi select.

```
Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Man try this:

```
ListBox1.TopIndex = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
```

It works. I always use it.